# How to trace submited Spark-SQL queries

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

when people execute Spark-SQL by:

1. `./bin/spark-sql` to  execute **THE-QUERY** on the command line OR
2. `./bin/spark-submit -f X.sql` to  execute **THE-QUERY** by a sql file

What exactly **THE-QUERY** is cannot be seen on the Spark WebUI  or history server.

It is hard to trace the source sql when exception happens.
So I am wondering if Spark itself actually has some features to log the submitted SQL ?